# Is every endomorphism of the sheaf of holomorphic functions on a disk a differential operator?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, sheaf-theory, complex-manifolds, micro-local-analysis

Let $D= \{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z| < 1\}$ be the unit disk. And consider the sheaf of holomorphic functions $\mathcal{O}_{D}$.

> **Question (?) :** Is there a sheaf endomorphisms $\phi : \mathcal{O}_D \to \mathcal{O}_D$ which is not a (possibly infinite order) differential operator. I.e. not of the form:
>
> $$\phi=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n(z) \partial^n$$
>
> Where $\partial =\frac{d}{d z}$ and $b_n \in \mathcal{O}_D$ .

EDIT: Suppose I require that $\phi$ be continuous w.r.t. to the natural frechet topology on $\mathcal{O}_D$ coming from uniform convergence on compact subsets, does the answer change?

Comment: Such an operator cannot be support non-increasing, by Peetre's theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peetre_theorem ).

Comment: @Rafael Mrđen: what about $\bar{\partial}$ ?

Comment: @RafaelMrđen I'm not sure how Peetre's theorem can be applied here, $\mathcal{O}_D$ can't be in any obvious sense a sheaf of smooth sections of a vector bundle as smooth functions don't act on it by multiplication.

Comment: Do you have any continuity constraint on sheaf endomorphisms?

Comment: Oh, I see I was wrong, thanks. Of course, $\phi$ need not a priori be extendable to continuous functions.

Comment: @SimonWadsley For starters i'm willing to ignore continuity entirely. Maybe a counterexample will convince me not to.

Comment: The paper I mention below shows that there is no counter-example in the continuous case. I don't know what happens without continuity.

Comment: where continuity means as in your edit.

Comment: @SimonWadsley That's cool! I would be really grateful If you could change your answer, so that understanding its content wouldn't require exiting the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably [this paper](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyushumfs/32/2/32_2_301/_article) answers your question negatively.

In particular it shows that if $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and the sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ of holomorphic functions on $X$ is given the topology of compact convergence then every continous endomorphism of $\mathcal{O}$ is given by a convergent $\mathcal{O}$-linear sum of operators $\partial_1^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots \partial_n^{\alpha_n}$ with $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Sorry but i'm really bad at french, could you perhaps state the main results of the paper?

Comment: If you can see MathSciNet https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=1978&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=pubyear&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=ishimura&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=509326.

Comment: You might also be interested in https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1092749255 which gives a derived version of the same theorem and is in English.